# How to use a personal pronoun where there could be multiple antecedents?

Tags: pronouns, ambiguity

When we say that,

Petter will give a book to Hari and he will come Dubai tomorrow.

Does the pronoun **he** refer to Petter or Hari?

Comment: If both are male, it's ambiguous.

Comment: **Personal** Pronouns.  To avoid ambiguity, say: "Peter will give Harry a book and come to Dubai tomorrow" or "Peter will give a book to Harry, who's coming to Dubai tomorrow."

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Ambiguous pronouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181652/ambiguous-pronouns) over on ELU.

Comment: My view is that since the pronoun (he) is in the subject position, it refers to the subject of the joined phrase (Peter).

Answer (score 2):

> How to use a personal pronoun where there could be multiple antecedents?

The 100% correct answer is to not use a pronoun if it's antecedent is ambiguous (this is different than the antecedent being indefinite.)  It's OK to be repetitive if you are trying to communicate clearly.

> Petter will give a book to Hari and Petter will come Dubai tomorrow.

Of course, context or previous information delivered earlier in the conversation may make this unnecessary.

> Petter had a plane ticket.  He's going to give a book to Hari and he'll come to Dubai tomorrow.

Here, we can *probably* safely deduce the second "he" in "he'll" refers to Petter, since he had a plane ticket and that usually means the person will be traveling.  You are relying on your listener/reader paying attention to all information here and thinking like you, and you can see the danger if your listener/reader might not be paying close attention.

So in contexts where you are instructing people, telling people what to do, or communicating with superiors, you probably want to avoid ambiguities and not use pronouns in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

> Pronouns A pronoun is a word that is used instead of a noun or noun
>   phrase. Pronouns refer to nouns that have already been mentioned or
>   are about to be mentioned. For instance, in example 1, below, the
>   pronoun she in the 2nd sentence refers to the noun phrase the school
>   principal in the 1st sentence. In example 2, he in the 1st clause
>   refers to Nathan in the 2nd clause. 1) The school principal spoke at the
>   special assembly in the auditorium. She also asked some students to
>   speak. 2) After he handed in his exam, Nathan was both anxious and
>   relieved at the same time.

[LINK](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/nouns-and-pronouns)  So a **pro**noun
 always refers to the noun mentioned.

> Petter will give a book to Hari and he will come Dubai tomorrow.

Should read: Peter will give a book to Harry when Harry comes to Dubai tomorrow.  This is the only clear way to make the point understandable.

It could change if we knew the sex of the named persons. Mary will give a book to Harry when he comes to Dubai tomorrow. If the reader is unfamiliar with feminine and masculine names from another culture, this would  still not be clear.

Answer (score 0):

> Peter will give the book to Harry and he will come to Dubai tomorrow. [I think that a certain book is meant]

The pronoun *he*, makes this sentence ambiguous regarding the person who is to arrive tomorrow.

To avoid this, you have either to change the placement of Harry as the object and then it becomes Peter who will come and give the book:

> Peter will come to Dubai tomorrow and he will give the book to Harry

or to put the information about Harry's arrival to Dubai, which may be relevant  or irrelevant to know  which Harry exactly is meant, in a  separate clause -- then it's Harry who's coming, and Peter remains the one who has the book to be given to Harry:

> Peter will give the book to Harry, who will come to Dubai tomorrow.
>
> Peter will give the book to Harry who will come to Dubai tomorrow.